# Updating SVN to 1.7 on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, svn, debian-squeeze

I tried to update my Subversion Client und Squeeze with 1.7. Therefore I extended the "/etc/apt/sources.list" with

```
deb http://opensource.wandisco.com/debian/ squeeze svn17
```

Downloaded their key from http://opensource.wandisco.com/wandisco-debian.gpg and added it to "apt-key".

But if i run now "apt-get update" I get some connection errors:

```
Get:1 http://opensource.wandisco.com squeeze Release.gpg [197 B]
Err http://opensource.wandisco.com/debian/ squeeze/svn17 Translation-en
  Connection failed
Err http://opensource.wandisco.com/debian/ squeeze/svn17 Translation-en_US
  Connection failed
Get:2 http://opensource.wandisco.com squeeze Release [2,693 B]
Ign http://opensource.wandisco.com squeeze/svn17 amd64 Packages
Err http://opensource.wandisco.com squeeze/svn17 amd64 Packages
  Connection failed
Fetched 2,890 B in 2s (1,269 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://opensource.wandisco.com/debian/dists/squeeze/svn17/i18n/Translation-en.bz2      Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://opensource.wandisco.com/debian/dists/squeeze/svn17/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Connection failed

W: Failed to fetch http://opensource.wandisco.com/debian/dists/squeeze/svn17/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  Connection failed

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

As expected the database did not get any update and I can't upgrade the SVN client.

If I manually surf to http://opensource.wandisco.com/debian/dists/squeeze/svn17 everything seems to be in place.

Why is the update failing?

Comment: What happens if you attempt to use curl to retrieve those URLs?

Comment: curl http://opensource.wandisco.com/debian/dists/squeeze/svn17/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Comment: and the i18n dirs even don't exist :( But I don't need anything else then english.

Answer (score 1):

This simple steps made it:

```
root@squeeze:~# wget -O - http://opensource.wandisco.com/wandisco-debian.gpg | apt-key add -
root@squeeze:~# apt-key list
pub   1024D/3BBF077A 2010-02-18
uid                  WANdisco (http://WANdisco.com - We Make Software Happen...) 
sub   2048g/955DA6AA 2010-02-18
root@squeeze:~# aptitude update && aptitude install subversion
root@squeeze:~# svn --version
svn, version 1.7.9 (r1462340)
   compiled Apr 25 2013, 14:44:34

Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people; see the NOTICE
file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
```

So, Works For Me (TM).

Comment: I did exactly this, and end up by the aptitude update with the same problem. :(

Comment: No proxy is defined. Even when I try to get the files from my client pc it's not working, because there is no i18n folder, which is expected.

Comment: Yes the update has no errors.

Comment: subversion is already installed in version 1.6: aptitude install subversion
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

Comment: the update also seems to have problems: Get:1 http://opensource.wandisco.com squeeze Release.gpg [197 B]
Err http://opensource.wandisco.com/debian/ squeeze/svn17 Translation-en
  Connection failed
Err http://opensource.wandisco.com/debian/ squeeze/svn17 Translation-en_US
  Connection failed
Get:2 http://opensource.wandisco.com squeeze Release [2,693 B]
Ign http://opensource.wandisco.com squeeze/svn17 amd64 Packages
Err http://opensource.wandisco.com squeeze/svn17 amd64 Packages
  Connection failed

Comment: This seems unrelated to `apt` itself. Try debugging networking issues, e.g. name resolution, etc.